# SQL select and join fields from 2 tables into one view in sqlite+flask app [python]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this code below for a view in a web app. This data is from the todo_court_changes table. I also have another table court_records that whose `county [county]` field I'd like to display with all this data. I'm quite the noob to SQL and do not know how to use the `cust_num` field which is in both tables to join both into this view. Please help. Thanks

```
select 
'<button class=''btn btn-xs btn-success'' onclick=''deleteRecordTODO('||id||')''><span class=''glyphicon glyphicon-ok''></span></button>&nbsp;<button class=''btn btn-primary btn-xs'' onclick=''showHistory("todo_court_changes","'||cust_num||'")''><span class=''glyphicon glyphicon-stats''></span></button>' as [Action],
--IMPORTANT: Don't change anything above this line.

strftime('%Y-%m-%d ',last_updated) || 
CASE WHEN  strftime('%H', last_updated) % 12 = 0 THEN 12 ELSE strftime('%H', last_updated) % 12 END 
|| ':' || strftime('%M', last_updated) || ' ' ||
CASE WHEN cast(strftime('%H', last_updated) as decimal) > 12 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'AM' END
as [Last Updated],
cust_num [Account], 
cust_name [Customer Name], 
current_owner [Current Owner], 
x_parcel [X Parcel], 
doc_type [Doc Type], 
recorded_date [Recorded Date],
book_page [Book Page]
-- is_active [Is_Active] --1 means active, 0 means not.
from todo_court_changes a
where  is_deleted=0
and (select count(*) from court_records where cust_num=a.cust_num and is_active=1) >= 1 
order by datetime(last_updated) desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a join, and you can get rid of the cumbersome second where clause:

```
SELECT 
    -- all your fields go here, prefix them with your table alias, eg a.field, b.county
FROM
    todo_court_changes a
    INNER JOIN court_records b ON a.cust_num = b.cust_num
WHERE
    a.isdeleted = 0
    b.isactive = 1
```